# Install .deb Package Error (dpkg error) Debian/Ubuntu machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, virtual-machine

I've been confronting an issue while installin .deb package on debian and ubuntu machine. i have tried various way but not able to install it.
it throws me an error below. I' trying to install snowagent on linux based machine. s

[image]

Not only this I've also tried following command ***sudo apt-get install agent.deb*** but each time when i run this command on shell it prompts me following error.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package agent.deb
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'agent.deb'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'agent.deb'
```

When i use "dpkg -s agent" its successful installation it prompts me status "***Install ok half-configured"***

Kindly assit.

Thanks

Comment: never heard of this packages, from witch repository are they?

Comment: please ask this question on https://askubuntu.com/